# Current year and two full years in predicate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a good way to write a prdicate in the where statement with the following condition?

Currrent year plus two full years back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use some date arithmetic?

```sql
WHERE YourColumn >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE())-2,0)
```

Comment: Or the more correct (`datetime2`-wise): `DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(SYSDATETIME()), 1, 1)`